# Generic Conditional recursive type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to create a typesafe builder class for charts and struggle getting it to work. I think this can be done but right now I dont know whats the problem.

My goal is to initialize the builder with the series-definition and then add the lines. After all lines have been added the builder should automatically return a build() function and not the "addLine()" function.
I am really struggling getting this to work and would be extremely thankfull for any help of other Typesript Developers.

```
const seriesDef = {
  'Turnover': {
   unit: '€'
 },
 'Turnover Compare': {
   unit: '€'
 },
 'Turnover Diff': {
   unit: '€'
 }
};

type SeriesDef = {
  [seriesName: string]: {unit: string}
}


type AddLineReturn<RemaingAfterLabelRemoved> = {
 addLine<NL extends Exclude<RemaingAfterLabelRemoved, NL>>(nextLabel: NL): 
 RemaingAfterLabelRemoved extends undefined? {build(): void}: 
 AddLineReturn<Exclude<RemaingAfterLabelRemoved, NL>>
}

function testTypeNarrow<const SeriesKeysRemainingT, SD extends SeriesDef, L extends keyof SD>(remainingSeriesDef: SD, label: L): SeriesKeysRemainingT extends undefined? {build(): void}: AddLineReturn<Exclude<SeriesKeysRemainingT, L>>{
  let remainingSeriesDefAfterLabelRemoved = {...remainingSeriesDef} ;
  delete remainingSeriesDefAfterLabelRemoved[label]
  const typedRemainingSeriesDef = remainingSeriesDef as Omit<SD, L>;
  type RemaingAfterLabelRemoved = Exclude<SeriesKeysRemainingT, L> & keyof typeof typedRemainingSeriesDef;


  const addLineReturnObj : AddLineReturn<Exclude<SeriesKeysRemainingT, L>> = {
    addLine<NL extends RemaingAfterLabelRemoved>(nextLabel: NL){
    return testTypeNarrow<RemaingAfterLabelRemoved, typeof typedRemainingSeriesDef, NL>(typedRemainingSeriesDef, nextLabel)
  }
}

if(remainingSeriesDef === undefined){
  return {
    build(){
      console.log("BUILDING")
    }
  }
}else{
  return addLineReturnObj;
 }
}

const narrowedWithoutTurnover = testTypeNarrow(seriesDef, 'Turnover')
narrowedWithoutTurnover
.addLine('Turnover Compare')
.addLine('Turnover Diff')
.build();
```

Comment: It's a lot easier to do and follow with a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's fix the *call signature*:

```
type AddLineReturn<K> = {
  addLine<P extends K>(nextLabel: P):
    Exclude<K, P> extends never ? { build(): void } : AddLineReturn<Exclude<K, P>>
}

function testTypeNarrow<SD extends SeriesDef, P extends keyof SD>(
  remainingSeriesDef: SD, label: P):
  Exclude<keyof SD, P> extends never ? { build(): void } : AddLineReturn<Exclude<keyof SD, P>>;
```

When you [`Exclude<K, P>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) the last member `P` from a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `K` it results in [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), not `undefined`.

And we don't want to wait until *after* the union is empty to return `{build(): void}`.  We want to return `{build(): void}` if the union *will be* empty.  So we're not checking if `K` is `never`, but if `Exclude<K, P>` is `never`.

And your `testTypeNarrow` typing is similar except that `K` is replaced by `keyof SD`.

Let's test it:

```
const narrowedWithoutTurnover = testTypeNarrow(seriesDef, 'Turnover')
narrowedWithoutTurnover
  .addLine('Turnover Compare')
  .addLine('Turnover Diff')
  .build();
```

Looks good. That compiles as desired.

---

As for the implementation, something like this should work:

```
function testTypeNarrow(remainingSeriesDef: SeriesDef, label: string) {
  const { [label]: extracted, ...rest } = remainingSeriesDef
  console.log("extracted " + label, extracted)
  return Object.keys(rest).length ? {
    addLine(nextLabel: string) { return testTypeNarrow(rest, nextLabel) }
  } : {
    build() {
      console.log("building")
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I don't know what you intend to do with each extracted property or what happens at the `build()` step, so you'll have to deal with that yourself.  Since it's recursively defined you'll need to figure out how to get information from outer scopes into inner scopes.  Closures, maybe?  An extra function parameter, maybe?  A state object that you mutate, maybe (not recommended if you want to reuse intermediate states)?  But I consider that offtopic here.

The point is that this behaves at runtime as expected:

```
const narrowedWithoutTurnover = testTypeNarrow(seriesDef, 'Turnover');
// "extracted Turnover",  { "unit": "€" } 

narrowedWithoutTurnover
  .addLine('Turnover Compare') // "extracted Turnover Compare",  { "unit": "€" } 
  .addLine('Turnover Diff') // "extracted Turnover Diff",  {  "unit": "€" } 
  .build(); // "building"
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmAnAlvCAReAzGBeGA3gFAwwDkAKgK6JggBuSZAXISaTFWMlK2YDUEZdgF8ANO0o06jRDADCIALYAHAIaJ4LNh07de5QSPGlJtBkhjpkWLFuI6uPPodLCiwgNxEiUAJ7L4GABlJFQMbDxtGABtBBQ0ADlVRXhWaBQwAHMAXVYCXSc4KAzMmDc3bz8AmABBABM6gBlkMHgAJXgoKQAeAGkAPkj7GFUG5tbugAUYeAAPKHgwOogYAYAKVvnG1QAjeAAbVkmASmZ2UgBRWeB9qjr4PtEYScG5haWV1pkYAH5CGB2VGQ+zqa1OMHoIGQdTKMFY9SaLXanR6VxudwevSeL367m8WC4wCgyHAMAW0Ao-ngSUQiBAAHdukF0DN5otlsFQmhMFhsaz3hyANbwXwgHDM-prdgaRSqFotTIheLhLCsZlPfa7A5HU7sNG3e7dYWi8XobGvNkfGBfCx-fKA4Gg8GQ6Gw+FjJEdLq0br6jFGkVi4Jm579fpeIgEsBEklgMloKCUgI0un0tYyuXcLJKsI8tVclUarWHIolY5RUCQWD5aKavb7XL8xCqInwOpPAB0XY00Fh+Az8uzBZ57ErEBA+3gHf2IEyawARG9m62YfOYABqGB1g5PJcthZ1Y7SlG0GAAeR2ACt4ESO8aIOmE8dp4tMlAABa-KKkUaI1obN5tnrNJigVct8g0b043JRMqRTBlH2gJ5NigICDnLNxXDhb8ASBEEwRw0gxwnKcZznecHRBBV5yPHRMLKPEiDHWAwHUVM2wAdR4d8QCoRMpHMWR8BgpNqTYhC4lzbAnlMaQmGOLwAHpFJgRd5mXA8YGoMwZHnJ5-nnRwoHnVh534NdhBgbxWNpBlOO43j+J0pB2A7X9xngNZZME+QlDUDQyHLZTVL3FctIE74FBUdR4D00h8kMvQTNU8zYVc9ykS87S5NkKwbECmBgrU4p9zbcLnNy6wsDi-5VKM5KzIsqzSA7SinQ8QqVIovC6mooA)